# Webapi returns html page instead of json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented an action filter attribute for token verification and if token is invalid then api response should return from this action filter.

```
    public class TokenValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                 bool isValidToken = FunctionToVerifyToken();
                 if (!isValidToken ))
                        {

                            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                            {
                                Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized user")
                            };
                            return;
                        }
               }
       }
```

**Response:**
It goes to _layout.cshtml and returns whole html page instead of just returning "Unauthorized user"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Sign in</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
        ...
```

**Update:**
controller where I'm using this token:

```
public class ServiceController : ApiController
    {
         [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [HttpGet]
        [HttpPost]
        [TokenValidation]
        public object ChangePassword()
        {
            //my logic is token is valid. It returns json data and works fine.
        }
}
```

The view returned is login page.

My `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Service", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints: null
            );

        }
}
```

Comment: How does the entire HTML page look like? What partial / view does it return? Also please add a controller / action where you're using this `TokenValidationAttribute`, that could probably help.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: have you used `[Authorize]` attribute at controller level or wherever your `FunctionToVerifyToken()` lives?

Comment: Try formatting string content as: StringContent(Json.Encode(new { message = "Unauthorized user" }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Comment: `[Authorize]` attribute is not used anywhere in webapi and I have formatted string content as `StringContent(Json.Encode(new { message = "Unauthorized user" }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")` but still returns whole html page.

Comment: take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834782/1939542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned response as:

```
actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Unauthorized user");
```

and it returned `"Unauthorized user"` instead of whole html page.

Answer (score 0):

In Global.ascx.cs add following line

- GlobalConfiguration.Configure(FilterConfig.Register);

In FilterConfig.cs register method

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new TokenValidationAttribute());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code are missing this below lines in your TokenValidationAttribute.cs action filter.
`base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext); return;` What this will do is it would get your formated result and display your result rather than displaying the view.