# C# Web API: Iterating Array and Append to HTML table

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a POST endpoint where on success, it will send an HTML email with the POST data. I am struggling trying to iterate over the JSON array of objects and appending that data to a HTML table.

JSON data:

```json
{
   "Submitter":[
      {
         "Obj1":[
            "test",
            "test2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Obj2":[
            "test3",
            "test4"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

TestingController:

```cs
    public class Testing2Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        public class Submitter
        {
            public List<string> Obj1 { get; set; }
            public List<string> Obj2 { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyData
        {
            public List<Submitter> Submitter { get; set; }
        }

        public string POST([FromBody] MyData data)
        {

            string composeTableObj1 = @"";
            string composeTableObj2 = @"";


            foreach (var item in data.Submitter)
            {
                composeTableObj1 += $"<tr>"; //start row tag
            //Column 1 Obj1 data
            if (item.Obj1 != null)
                {
                    foreach (var objItem in item.Obj1)
                    {
                        composeTableObj1 += $"<td>{objItem}</td>";
                    }
                }

                //Column 2 Obj2 data
                if (item.Obj2 != null)
                {

                    foreach (var objItem in item.Obj2)
                    {
                        composeTableObj1 += $"<td>{objItem}</td>";
                    }
                }
                composeTableObj1 += $"</tr>"; //end row tag


        }

            string body = @$"<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Object 1</th>
    <th>Object 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{composeTableObj1}
</tbody>
</table>
";

            return body;
        }
    }
```

The above code gives me the following undesired result:

```
| Object 1 | Object 2 |
|----------|----------|
| test     | test2    |
| test3    | test4    |
```

This is the desired result I'm after:

```
| Object 1 | Object 2 |
|----------|----------|
| test     | test3    |
| test2    | test4    |
```

Been stuck on this for quite some time, TIA!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075865/webapi-returns-html-page-instead-of-json/51076576 please go through this link.

Comment: @AmalPs that post you linked has absolutely nothing to do with my question

Comment: String concatenation in a loop is very inefficient, because it creates a lot of garbage in memory.

Therefore, you need to use either StringBuilder, or write directly to the output stream.

Alternatively, you can use the capabilities of the `XElement` class from the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace - this will allow you to create html in an object-oriented style.

Another way is to create html in a view using Razor.

You have chosen the worst way, inefficient, error-prone and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your HTML is a bit off - writing HTML like this can be tedious. I am guessing based off of the hard coded table headers in the HTML and the structure of the `Submitter` class that you will only ever have two `Objn` items in your JSON.  If this is true, you can ditch the `foreach` loop for a `for` loop, and get the value out of `data.Submitter[n]` using the loops iterator:

```cs
public string Post([FromBody] MyData data)
{
    string composeTableObj = ""; 

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Submitter.Count(); i++)
    {
        composeTableObj += $"<tr>"; //start row tag
        composeTableObj += $"<td>{data.Submitter[0].Obj1[i]}</td>";
        composeTableObj += $"<td>{data.Submitter[1].Obj2[i]}</td>";
        composeTableObj += $"</tr>"; //end row tag
    }

    return @$"<table><thead><tr><th>Object 1</th><th>Object 2</th></tr></thead><tbody>{composeTableObj}</tbody></table>";
}
```

Rendered:

[image: html]

Returned HTML:

```html
<table><thead><tr><th>Object 1</th><th>Object 2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>test</td><td>test3</td></tr><tr><td>test2</td><td>test4</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Obviously, this isn't very dynamic.  If you find you need more `Objn`, you'll need to update the `Submitter` class, and you will have to add to the code within the loop (and add another header for your HTML).

---

If you have more items in the `Obj` arrays, you can do the following:

```cs
public string Post([FromBody] MyData data)
{
    string composeTableObj = "";

    int obj1Count = data.Submitter[0].Obj1.Count;
    int obj2Count = data.Submitter[1].Obj2.Count;

    int loopCount = obj1Count >= obj2Count ? obj1Count : obj2Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
    {
        string obj1String = obj1Count <= i ? " " : data.Submitter[0].Obj1[i];
        string obj2String = obj2Count <= i ? " " : data.Submitter[1].Obj2[i];

        composeTableObj += $"<tr>"; //start row tag
        composeTableObj += $"<td>{obj1String}</td>";
        composeTableObj += $"<td>{obj2String}</td>";
        composeTableObj += $"</tr>"; //end row tag
    }

    return  @$"<table><thead><tr><th>Object 1</th><th>Object 2</th></tr></thead><tbody>{composeTableObj}</tbody></table>";
}
```

This first gets the greater of the two `.Count`s between your `Obj` lists to set the loops condition, and then performs an index bounds check.  If the `objnCount` is less than or equal to `i`, set it to a space, otherwise take the value for its respective `Obj` list.  With 6 items in `Obj2` and only 2 items in `Obj1`, the HTML looked like this:

[image: rendered html with more objs]

Returned HTML:

```html
<table><thead><tr><th>Object 1</th><th>Object 2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>test</td><td>test3</td></tr><tr><td>test2</td><td>test4</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td>test5</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td>test6</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td>test7</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td>test8</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: This is great although like you said, its not very dynamic. If there are more values in the ```Obj1 JSON array``` for example then it won't be rendered because its only looping until ```data.Submitter.Count``` ends. Is there a way to make it a bit more dynamic if in case ```Obj1 or Obj2 arrays``` contain more values?

Comment: @ayushlal you could get the highest count of the of items in Obj1 or Obj2 and use that as the loops condition, and perform a count check on each index within the respective Obj lists. If `i` is > then the Obj's count, then insert a blank string for the `<td>`, otherwise insert its value. I am assuming the blank won't throw the HTML off. Probably safer to insert `" "` So if Obj1 has 5 items, and Obj2 has 6, you'd loop 6 times, and on the 6th iteration, `data.Submitter[0].Obj1[i]` would be out of bounds, so insert a space for it.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that, I was thinking the same thing on the lines. If you could please update your answer that would be awesome!

Comment: @ayushlal looks to work.